Cypress - how to wait until user input
I am new to Cypress and have the following question.
I try to write a test for creating a user account.
After I enter an email, the app will send a Code (a 6-digit number) to the email.
I want to pause the Cypress test until the user reads his e-mail and enters the code.
After the code is entered the test should continue to press the "confirm"-Button.
How can I do this?
I can check if the inputs for the code are not empty, with ".should('not.have.value', '');". But how can I wait the test until this condition is true?
it('Create Account', () => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/');
  // press some buttons
  cy.get('.btn').click();
  cy.get('.bottom-box--inner > .flex > .btn').click();
  cy.get('.flex > .btn-primary').click();
  cy.get('.flex > .btn-primary').click();
  cy.get('#ion-input-0').click();
  // enter username
  cy.get('#ion-input-0').type('username');
  cy.get('#ion-input-1').click();
  // enter user email
  cy.get('#ion-input-1').type('user@email.com');
  cy.get('.p-5 > .btn').click();



  //now here opens in my app a window where i have to put the 6-digit-code that was sent to my email.
  // i want to wait the user to enter this code and then continue the test
  

  
  // press confirm button
  cy.get('app-otp.ng-star-inserted > .ion-no-border > .ios > .p-5 > .btn').click();
});


There is actually a pause command.

Stop cy commands from running and allow interaction with the application under test. You can then "resume" running all commands or choose to step through the "next" commands from the Command Log.

If you want to fully automate, there are plugins like cypress-mailosaur.
Adapting here the code from the docs. The only problem is the popup window.
cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {sentTo: emailAddress})
  .then(email => {
    expect(email.subject).to.equal('Verification code');
    cy.get('#ion-input-3').type(email.text.slice(20,26))
  })

